# R plotting on a single figure

Tags: r, data-visualization

The question I have to answer is:

> As an exploratory investigation, visualise the data in a set of pairs plots between the two response variables (ES and NS) and the 5 explanatory variables (Area, Anear, Dist, DistSC, Elevation).

My teacher said:

> The question is asking you to provide some visual summary of the data, so that we can see the dependencies. The simplest way to do this, is to plot each variable against every other variable. This would be 7 choose 2 = 21 plots. Fortunately, R has a way of producing these in a single figure, rather than producing pages and pages of output.

But I have been unable to work out how to do this, can anyone help?

Comment: We welcome questions like this, @user42835, but we treat them differently. Please tell us what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you are stuck, & we'll try to provide hints to get you unstuck. To better understand the process, you should read the [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) for the `[self-study]` tag.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you are looking for is a **scatterplot matrix**, which shows the scatterplot for each pair of variables in a single grid.

To do this in R, you can use the `pairs()` function. For instance, if your data are stored in data frame `df`, and your variables are called `x1` through `x5`, you could do:

`pairs(~x1+x2+x3+x4+x5, data=df)`

[This website](http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/scatterplot.html) provides similar and more complex examples of scatterplot matrices in R.

Comment: Agreed. `pairs(ES/NS~Area+Anear+Dist+DistSC+Elevation, data=galapagos)` is prbly what @user42835 is looking for for the question as I think [s]he is working through Weisberg's Applied Linear Regression book in a course, and the `galapagos` data set is from the `alr3` package used in it.

Comment: Ah, thanks for your comment @hrbrmstr, I was not aware of this data set.